# How to get nested count via Eloquent?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have simple nested tree model:

**Page table**

```
id
owner_id
title
```

Any page can have similar Pages related by key `owner_id` and refers to the same table records.

How to get some page with count of the nested pages by `id` through Eloquent?

In a native SQL i can do something like this:

```
SELECT pages.*, count(subPage.id) AS childCount
FROM pages AS page
LEFT JOIN pages AS subPage ON (subPage .owner_id = page.id)
....
```

Something like this:

`$page->childsCount` will return count of related sub pages.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you already have `pages()` relationship defined, you can use [`withCount()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models) method:

```
Page::withCount('pages')->first();
```

> If you want to count the number of results from a relationship without actually loading them you may use the `withCount` method, which will place a `{relation}_count` column on your resulting models.

Comment: Its a same table. I need relationships? And pust updated.

Comment: @Stanislav if you want to use Eloquent for this you need to define a relationship. It can be relationship between `Page` and `Page`

Answer (score 2):

I found the easiest way to count nested `hasMany` relationship counts in Laravel. Suppose we have three models with has many and nested `hasMany` relationships:

#### Category Model:

```
public function subCategories()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Subcategory');
    }
```

#### Subcategory Model

```
public function products()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Product');
    }


$categories = $this->categoryRepository
    ->with([
        'subCategories' => function ($query) {
            $query->withCount('products');
        }])
    ->whereIn("id", $categories_id)
    ->orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();
```

You will get the product count using all these three steps.

Answer (score 0):

By having a relation between `Page` and `Owner` you can do this:

```
$page->owner->pages->count();
```

Answer (score 0):

Was solved in this way

in Page Model

```
...

    protected $childCount = 0;


    public function pages()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Page::class, 'owner_id');
    }

    public function childCount()
    {
        return $this->childCount ? $this->childCount : $this->pages()->select('id')->count();
    }
...
```

And we get access to sub pages count via `$page->childCount()` model method.